# How does Rails params parse hash from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and got curious how the params method works. I understand what it does, but how?

Is there a built-in method that takes a hash string like so

```
"cat[name]"
```

and translates it to

```
{ :cat => { :name => <assigned_value> } }
```

?

I have attempted to write the params method myself but am not sure how to write this functionality in ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GET parameters are set from `ActionDispatch::Request#GET`, which extends `Rack::Request#GET`, which uses [`Rack::QueryParser#parse_nested_query`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/query_parser.rb).

The POST parameters are set from `ActionDispatch::Request#POST`, which extends `Rack::Request#POST`, which uses [`Rack::Multipart#parse_multipart`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/multipart.rb). That splays through several more files in [`lib/rack/multipart`](https://github.com/rack/rack/tree/master/lib/rack/multipart).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproduction of the functionality of the method (note: this is NOT how the method works). Helper methods of interest: `#array_to_hash` and `#handle_nested_hash_array`

```
require 'uri'

class Params
  def initialize(req, route_params = {})
    @params = {}

    route_params.keys.each do |key|
      handle_nested_hash_array([{key => route_params[key]}])
    end

    parse_www_encoded_form(req.query_string) if req.query_string
    parse_www_encoded_form(req.body) if req.body
  end

  def [](key)
    @params[key.to_sym] || @params[key.to_s]
  end

  def to_s
    @params.to_s
  end

  class AttributeNotFoundError < ArgumentError; end;

  private

  def parse_www_encoded_form(www_encoded_form)
    params_array = URI::decode_www_form(www_encoded_form).map do |k, v|
      [parse_key(k), v]
    end

    params_array.map! do |sub_array|
      array_to_hash(sub_array.flatten)
    end

    handle_nested_hash_array(params_array)
  end

  def handle_nested_hash_array(params_array)
    params_array.each do |working_hash|
      params = @params

      while true
        if params.keys.include?(working_hash.keys[0])
          params = params[working_hash.keys[0]]
          working_hash = working_hash[working_hash.keys[0]]
        else
          break
        end

        break if !working_hash.values[0].is_a?(Hash)
        break if !params.values[0].is_a?(Hash)
      end

      params.merge!(working_hash)
    end
  end

  def array_to_hash(params_array)
    return params_array.join if params_array.length == 1

    hash = {}
    hash[params_array[0]] = array_to_hash(params_array.drop(1))

    hash
  end

  def parse_key(key)
    key.split(/\]\[|\[|\]/)
  end
end
```